# How does luck affect you in Diaries of a Spaceport Janitor

Tags: diaries-of-a-spaceport-janitor

In Diaries of a Spaceport Janitor the game revolves almost entirely around luck, but it's so ethereal it isn't clear how it actuals affects gameplay. Does luck affect the quality of trash left on the ground, sale prices, or likelihood of your municipal credits being eaten by a Red Scarf?

Having either high or low luck doesn't seem to modify the gameplay seriously. My credits are still consumed and life is still difficult. The game, being as allegorical as it is, may not actually use the stat as an analogy for hoping for luck to help one escape poverty. But the game's mechanics are so connected to the idea of luck I don't want to assume one way or the other.